# how override attr_accessible role ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on, attr-accessible

how override attr_accessible role for field :name in Tag model in ActsAsTaggableOn gem ?

I want some things like that in Tag model ...

```
attr_accessible :name, :as => [:default, :admin]
```

for allow me to edit field name of tag by admin role

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can monkey patch acts_as_taggable_on by creating a file in config/initializers and adding the following lines. Restart your rails server for changes to take effect.

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  attr_accessible :name, :as => [:default, :admin]
end
```